# Help with an apparently bored player

Tags: dnd-3.5e, gm-techniques

I have a group of 5 players, 3 are long time veterans and we have been playing together for 15 years, the other is a newcomer who is actually liking the game a lot, and there's a 5th player that joined recently, the gf of one of the veterans. She is also new to roleplaying games.

I'm running an introductory and modified version of Wizard's amulet/Crucible of Freya (Chauntea) on the Forgotten Realms setting, adding a bit more detail and NPCs and preparing the background so the players put their eye on the Silver Marches. Everything was running smoothly until the new player joined the game. She seems to dislike everything that happens in the game. Roleplaying with the other players and with the NPCs at the town seemed to bore her, more action packed sessions like the assault on the orc infested fortress got her sleepy, and exploring a wizards sanctum and laboratory also looked unappealing to her.

Most of the time she stays quiet, and when me or another player ask her directly if she wants to do something she does, but just because she has to. Whats worst is that after 2 or 3 hours into the session, she starts arguing with her bf about gods know what, and that breaks the good atmosphere of the game and the session turns uncomfortable.

I don't really know what to do to make her enjoy the game. Maybe she doesn't like the other players, maybe she doesn't like me, or maybe she doesn't like the setting/adventure.

Any ideas on how to approach this situation?

Edit:

First, thanks everyone for the input. I guess asking her it's the first thing to do, but this behaviour was new to me and I wasn't sure what to do.

Scott, they started playing as level 1 characters, and she joined when the rest of the party were level 2 and yesterday they all progressed to level 3. We are only using the players handbook, DM guide, monster manual and Forgotten Realms setting and the Quintessential books for each class to add a little more flavour to the characters. Initially it was an introductory adventure for the new guy, so I wanted to keep it simple to give him a general idea of the setting and our game style.

The 3 veterans are playing a rogue, a bard and a druid (her bf). The other new guy started as a barbarian, and the new girl is playing a fighter. So far no player kills, they are being very VERY lucky (and smart) So far they have battled low level undead such as zombies, orcs, a low level necromancer and a 5th level cleric, so there are not a lot of rules floating around.

I'm all against creating encounters that take forever to resolve, I played Rolemaster for a long time and I learned to hate those kind of encounters that lasted for hours, so even if we are using an existing module I write everything in my book so I have a quick reference of everything at hand. I don't think it's a pace issue, as I try to focus more and what the characters want to do and less on the strict rules, although I use the rules for solving the situations, of course.

Edit 2: KRyan pointed a very similar thread so I think this one doesn't add much to the web. Now its me playing the newb. Ouch! So yeah, this question is very similar to the other one so close it. Thanks again for the input guys.

Comment: **Strongly** suspect this is a duplicate of [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/36423/4563), but since I cannot vote to close without unilaterally closing a 3.5 question, I'm going to leave this here. Winblood, if your question requires answers different from those to the linked question, please edit your question to explain what about those answers is unsuitable and what you specifically need. If those answers solve your problem, say so and we will close this as a duplicate.

Comment: I merged the answers over so that they can live on.